# How to show two norms are equivalent on periodic Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in H^s[0,2\pi]$, be Sobolev space of periodic functions then we have the following norm
$$ \Vert f\Vert_{s}=\{ \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} (1+m^2)^s\vert \widehat{f_m}\vert^2 \}^{1/2}$$
(Given in Linear Integral equation by Rainer Kress ch. 8)
Further the standard sobolev norm would be
$$\Vert f\Vert_{s}= \{\sum_{k\leq s}\Vert D^{(k)}f\Vert_{L^2([0,2\pi])}^2\}^{1/2}.$$

The benefit of the first definition over the second is that it can be defined for $s\geq 0$, whereas the second requires $s$ to be an integer.

Can anyone please provide me with some hint on how to show these both norms are equivalent when $s$ is an integer? Thanks.

Comment: Your first norm doesn't have f in the definition. Write f as a fourier series and use holder

Comment: Thanks for notifying that. Now I have updated the question.

Comment: This follows from Parseval, once you know what the Fourier coefficients of $D^kf$ are (in terms of the coefficients of $f$).

Comment: Thank you so much.